# Filtering out tuples

Tags: python

I am having some trouble altering a function I created which calculates the derivative of a multi variable function. The function accepts functions as tuples, for example 3x^2 - 11 is represented by the list within my code. I am suppose to change my function to make it filter out any tuples with a zero as one of its values. So in this example I would have to remove the second tuple with a zero as its second value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using the filter and lambda expression but I am new to python and got confused when trying to apply it to tuples within a list.

```
three_x_squared_minus_eleven = [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]

def find_derivative(ft):
   i=0
   Length= list(range(len(ft)))
   result=()
   for term in Length:
      Multi_prime=((ft[i][1]*ft[i][0]),(ft[i][1]-1))
      result+=(Multi_prime,)
      i+=1
   return result


Result=(find_derivative(three_x_squared_minus_eleven))
```

This function works fine I just need to add filtering functionality to remove any tuples with a zero as one of its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to filter out any tuple that contains a 0:

```
ft = [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]
ft = [x for x in ft if 0 not in x]    
print(ft)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 2)]
```